# How to change the value of ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE from template side?

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I use Django Endless Paginator plugin.
I try to change the value of  ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE from template side.
As default is 10.
I want to realize some dropbox where the user can change between (Example: 10,20,50,100 Objects).

Thanks for answer, but something not work property.

**1. I have view.py**

```
def adv_search(request):
objects = None
if request.GET.get('key'):
    form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        repo = Repository()
        objects = list(repo.find_objects('*'+form.cleaned_data['key'] +'*', type=FileObject, chunksize=20))
    return render(request, 'templates/adv_search.html', {'form': form, 'objects': objects })
return render(request, 'templates/adv_search.html', {'form': AdvancedSearchForm(), 'objects': objects})
```

**2. Then forms.py**

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
key = forms.CharField(max_length=500, label="", widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'label'}))
show_props = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = (("pid", "pid"),("title", "title"),("type","type"),("source","source"),("date","date"),("publisher","publisher"),("subject","subject"),("label","label"),("cDate","cDate"),("mDate","mDate")),required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'my-class'}))
paginator = forms.ChoiceField(choices =(('10', '10'),('20','20'), ('50','50'), ('100','100')) ,required=False, )
```

**3. adv_search.html**

```
  {% paginate paginator objects %}
{% for obj in objects %}    

...

<div class="paginator">
{% get_pages %}
    {{ pages.first_as_arrow }}
{% show_pages %}
    {{ pages.last_as_arrow }}
    <form method="get">
    {{ form.paginator }}
    <input type="submit" Value="Go">
     </form>
    {{ pages.total_count }} total objects
</div>
```

Everything works except select

Thanks Andrey

Answer (score 0):

You can have a form which will set pagination per page and then use that submitted value in template. Here is an example:

## View

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Entry

def endless_view(request):
    pagination_per_page = request.GET.get('per_page', 10)
    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'pagination_per_page':
                  pagination_per_page, 'entries': entries})
```

## Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load endless %}
{% block content %}
    {#  #}
    <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="per_page">
            <option value="10">10 per page</option>
            <option value="20">20 per page</option>
            <option value="50">50 per page</option>
            <option value="100">100 per page</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" Value="Go">
    </form>
    {% paginate pagination_per_page entries %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {# your code to show the entry #}
    {% endfor %}
    {% show_pages %}
{% endblock content %}
```

## Reference

1. http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html